# Which state's defensive driving test to take in case of out-of-state speeding ticket?

Tags: driving, illinois, speeding, oklahoma

A friend, who is resident of IL and has an IL DL, got a speeding ticket in Oklahoma, which they refused to sign. They were charged to drive at 61 mph in a 40 mph zone with a ticket of $259. Can they take a defensive driving test to get the points off? If, yes which state's test they need, OK or IL?

Note that this is their first ever ticket.

Answer (score 1):

Points reduction, for points assessed by Oklahoma, is possible, see [here](https://oklahoma.gov/dps/faqs/suspension-revocation-of-driving-privilege-faq/point-system-faq.html): "Two (2) points shall be credited to a person's driving record upon successful completion of an *approved Driver Improvement/Defensive Driving Course*". There is, apparently, no authoritative state-wide published list of such courses. In the case of [OK City](https://www.okc.gov/departments/municipal-court/driving-school), they give you a number to call (or else show up at city all) to make the request. So it would depend on the local policy.

Comment: The friend I am talking about has a Illinois Driver's License. Will they still have to take the exam/course with OK? Or they will have to take with IL?

Comment: The ticket is issued by OK, and OK rules govern the points. IL may modify the points assigned by OK, so in terms of "bottom line effect", both states are involves and have discretion. Lawyer and legal advice etc. but start with the state reporting the offense, i.e. OK. The general rule is that IL assesses points as though the offense had occurred in IL.